# use Linq to parsing xml , import namespace. still can't read xml correctly, WHY?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xml-namespaces

my language is asp.net. and I use Linq to parsing xml file. but this xml file have set namespace. 
before load xml file. I try to import xml namespace. but still can't parsing xml correctly.

```
Imports <xmlns="abc">

<html>
<head>
<title>Do-Life</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="../../img/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs)
    If not isPostBack Then
....
Dim TYPINFO As XElement = XElement.Load(server.MapPath(filename))
    Dim tinfos As IEnumerable(Of XElement)      
    tinfos = From tf In TYPINFO...<typhinfo> Select tf
....
....
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cwbtyphfcst xmlns="abc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cwb.wfc.typhoonfcstCE/namespace typhooninfor.xsd">
<announcement>
    ...
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have put on the code.

Comment: @user6919 your XML must have an 'ns' namespace in there. Please show the full XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders when I remove 'ns' for the default namespaceprefix, I still can't parsing xml correctly. Do you know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have know the issue.

If I modify the xml content as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cwbtyphfcst xmlns:ns="abc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cwb.wfc.typhoonfcstCE/namespace typhooninfor.xsd">
<announcement>
...
```

identify the namespace prefix name as "ns"

and import the namespace as

```
Imports <xmlns:ns="abc">
```

finally, linq is work everything.